# Custom user provider for symfony2

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am going to create custom user provider for my web site, and there is no such concept for user as "username" and "password"(actually there is something like password but it called differently). 
In documentation said that User entity must implements UserInterface from security bundle, which has such methods like getUsername, getPassword. 
Can I make it with my own fields? Or Should I use names collisions(for example, getUsername would return my unique field) for implementing my behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. you only have to implement the interface.`getUsername()` can be anything you can identify your user by.(or even not in a faulty implementation)